# Converting and Implicit JOIN into a Corresponding Explicit JOIN

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to convert the inner subquery of the query below into an *explicit* `JOIN`.

```
SELECT *
FROM `files`
WHERE `version` = (
    SELECT `temp`.`version`
    FROM `files` AS `temp`
    WHERE `temp`.`location` = `files`.`location`
    AND temp.name = `files`.name
    ORDER BY `temp`.`version` DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY `location`, `name`
```

I tried the following, however, I end up getting an incorrect result set:

```
SELECT *
FROM `files`
WHERE `version` = (
    SELECT `temp`.`version`
    FROM `files` AS `temp`
    JOIN files ON `temp`.`location` = `files`.`location` AND temp.name = `files`.name
    ORDER BY `temp`.`version` DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY `location`, `name`
```

How would I do this in SQLite?

Comment: Huh?  What is wrong with the first query?  What does adding an extra `join` do for you?

Comment: TBH, it works. I'm just trying to understand why my explicit join is not working. Purely academic. :-)

Comment: Also, holy crap you have a lot of rep! haha

Comment: Just to add more details, the first query returns 2 results. The second query, however, returns 1 result. I'm just trying to make sense of the variance.

Comment: . . The queries are so different that the question makes no sense.  The first is a correlated subquery and the second is not.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference.